# How to catch a external exception

Tags: c#, .net, dll, datagridview, vlc

I'm using the nVLC dll's for using the VLC Media Player within my application. It works like a charm except for one thing. I have a DataGridView with a list of movies. When I select a movie from that DataGridView it starts playing the movie within the panel that is handled by nVLC. I also use filters to filter the movies within the DataGridView. When I do this a couple of times I get an error from the nVLC DLL:

> CallbackOnCollectedDelegate occurred
>
> Managed Debugging Assistant 'CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Soft.UltimateMovieManager\Soft.UltimateMovieManager\bin\Release\Soft.UltimateMovieManager.vshost.exe'.
>
> Additional information: A callback was made on a garbage collected
>   delegate of type
>   'nVLC.Implementation!Implementation.VlcEventHandlerDelegate::Invoke'.
>   This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When
>   passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the
>   managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be
>   called.

The problem is that I can't catch that exeption. Even when I set a try/catch on the application itself, it still can't be handled.

Is this something I can resolve myself or is this a problem of the nVLC dll I use?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(video_url))
{
    if (pnlStartVideo != null)
    {
        pnlStartVideo.Dispose();
    }

    pnlStartVideo = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
    pnlStartVideo.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
    pnlStartVideo.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
    pnlStartVideo.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    pnlStartVideo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(pnlStartInfo.Location.X, (pnlStartInfo.Location.Y + (pnlStartInfo.Height - 1)));
    pnlStartVideo.Name = "pnlStartVideo";
    pnlStartVideo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(275, 153);
    pnlStartVideo.TabIndex = 3;

    tpStart.Controls.Add(pnlStartVideo);

    m_factory = new MediaPlayerFactory(true);
    m_player = m_factory.CreatePlayer<IDiskPlayer>();
    m_player.WindowHandle = pnlStartVideo.Handle;
    m_player.Events.PlayerStopped += Events_PlayerStopped;
    UISync ui = new UISync();
    ui.Init(this);

    m_media = m_factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>(video_url);

    m_player.Open(m_media);
    m_media.Parse(true);

    m_media.Events.StateChanged += Events_StateChanged;

    m_player.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' ...

It is not a catchable exception since it is not an exception at all.  A managed debugging assistant is helper code added to the debugger that can detect various mishaps at runtime.  This one steps in when it sees the VLC player trying to use a disposed delegate object.  Without the debugger your program will keel over and die in a much worse way, an AccessViolationException, not catchable either since it is native code that fails.

Looking at the VLC wrapper source code, you must create the `m_player` instance only **once** to avoid this failure mode.  When you create it over and over again like you do now, the previous IDiskPlayer instances are not reference anywhere anymore.  The garbage collector will collect them, big kaboom when the native VLC code makes the callback to fire an event.  The wrapper also doesn't implement proper cleanup that I can see, ensuring that the native code cannot fire events anymore when the object is disposed.

Making the `m_player` variable *static* is strongly recommended.  Assign it just once.

Fixing the wrapper would require writing the equivalent of initializeEventsEngine() but setting all the callbacks back to null.  This is not necessarily straight-forward, there are probably threading races involved.  Taking a dependency on this code is a liability, you might want to keep shopping.

Comment: Thank you so much.. it sounds like this should work. I'm going to try this later today and will mark this as the answer for my question when it works. I've been shopping for a long time to find a nice VLC wrapper but without luck, do you know any good working VLC wrappers maybe?

Comment: Hmm, no, only wrappers that are debugged by programmers that contribute their changes back to the open source project ever work relatively trouble-free.